# Why I'm getting 404 on local GitLab installation?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

The title pretty much says it all. I just installed GitLab CE on my Ubuntu 18.04, reconfigured for default settings, checked if the server is running with `service gitlab-runsvdir status` as it is running. But when I go to the IP assigned to the server I get 404 from the server.

[image]

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.42.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1 metric 100   <--
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

[image]

How can I fix this ?

**update:**

I edited this line `external_url 'http://192.168.1.100/'` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` as it's a file that supposed to be edited upon installation. No change though. When I visit 192.168.1.100 in my browser I get 404.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part of the displayed error message in your browser is:

> or you don't have permission to view it

That implied an authentication issue.

Open a new browser session in incognito mode and try again: it should request a username/password: make sure to enter the admin one.